# how to open a hyperlink in new window

Tags: extjs, hyperlink, window

I am using `ExtJS 2.3.0`

I have a link as follows-

```
{ id: 'Id1', type: 'int', header: "Click me", navigateUrl: "www.google.com", width: 60 }
```

clicking this opens the page in same window. I want to open this in new window. I know I can use `window.open` but how can I write it inside navigateURL

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by adding  `"target": "_blank"`

```
{ id: 'Id1', type: 'int', header: "Click me", navigateUrl: "www.google.com", "target": "_blank", width: 60 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{ id: 'Id1', type: 'int', header: "Click me", navigateUrl: "www.google.com", target: "_blank", width: 60 }
```